# Digging custom tags out of Polymer element definitions

Tags: javascript, polymer

Dealing with some relics of the past in our elements' implementation, we've hit a snag reaching into `<template>` elements externally to retrieve specific content. For example, we leave a `<script id="ceci-definition">` in our elements which contains some meta data about the element. Looks like this:

```
<polymer-element>
  <template>
    <script id="ceci-definition">{ ... }</script>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Later, we try to retrieve it using something ugly like this:

```
window.CustomElements.registry[elementName].prototype.element.impl.querySelector('template').content.querySelector('script#ceci-definition');
```

I'm in the process of moving those definition s to be direct children of the  which encloses them, which makes reaching in for that data much easier. Like this:

```
<polymer-element>
  <script id="ceci-definition">{ ... }</script>
  <template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

and slightly less ugly...

```
window.CustomElements.registry[elementName].prototype.element.impl.querySelector('script#ceci-definition');
```

My question: is there a cleaner, Polymer way to reach into the `<polymer-element>` tag for something?

Note: Trying not to place this meta data on the object which is passed to `Polymer()`.

Comment: Ugh, I would definitely avoid using that brittle JS statement. If the outside needs access to it (cleary you do), why avoid exposing this data as a property on the element?

Comment: Also note, to reach into an element's shadow dom, you can use `.shadowRoot`: `document.querySelector(elementName).shadowRoot.querySelector(...)`

Comment: if you have an instance of your polymer-element on the page, e.g. `<foo-bar>` you can get a hold of it and do .element, that way you don't have to go through the window.CustomElements.registry (which will totally not work with native custom elements).

another trick: use `document.createElement(elementName).element` to get a hold of the polymer-element. Note this only works if you know it's a polymer-element and not some other kind of custom element.

Comment: Unfortunately, we need to get at this data before the element is instantiated/dropped on the page. :/

Comment: @jmesserly, that's a good idea. Want to avoid a potentially large memory footprint though. Means we'd have to instantiate an element to get at its meta-data, which is sub-optimal, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [core-meta](https://github.com/Polymer/core-meta/) is for.

Comment: Excellent! I'll check it out and see if it solves our problem.

Comment: If you're interested, here's where we're tracking it in Appmaker: https://github.com/mozilla-appmaker/appmaker/issues/1104

Comment: Here is some sample code: http://jsbin.com/xokar/5/edit. I tried to capture a lot of detail and I may have made it inscrutable. Happy to clarify if I can. Also, I used `polymer-meta` (which is the old name for `core-meta`) because `core-meta` isn't in stable branch yet.

Comment: Thanks! The design of core-meta was super handy. Wrote a custom version here: https://github.com/mozilla-appmaker/appmaker/pull/1148/files