# Are there any established patterns for global settings/state for components?

Tags: polymer

Currently, I've got a component something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-widget" constructor="MyWidget">
  <script>
    Polymer('my-widget', {});
    MyWidget.someGlobalConfigValue = 1234;
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Are there other approaches to this that I should consider?

(aside: It'd be neat if `Polymer()` returned the constructor, so I don't have to force a name)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. In particular, when you say `so I don't have to force a name` it's confusing. Without a name, how do you access your config value globally?

You may be interested in core-meta as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947490/digging-custom-tags-out-of-polymer-element-definitions/22960252?noredirect=1#comment35389829_22960252.

Comment: If Polymer() returned the built constructor, you wouldn't have to reference it by name. I.e. https://gist.github.com/nevir/11075455

Comment: Then who can ever access `someGlobalState`? Without a reference to the constructor how do you ever extract that information?

Comment: Sorry, in that case, it would be private state, as an alternative to the monostate pattern. The only real benefit in my eyes is that it makes it easier to inspect those values - and maybe makes inheriting a "singleton" element more straightforward (but poorly encapsulated).

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but you are avoiding the practical question. Do you intend to access `this.constructor.someGlobalState` from instances?

Comment: In any case, we cannot return the constructor from Polymer() because that reference is not available synchronously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One pattern is to use a component for configuration: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global

Comment: Hmm, interesting. At first glance that seems overkill; but it does grant all the data binding goodness. That pattern seems to work great for globals that are used only internally to the main element. In my case I'd like to provide a value that can be tuned externally (global config, not state)

Comment: Actual use case: the element is a handy-dandy link shortn-er, and it would like to maintain a cache of the N most recently generated short links (but I'd like page owners to tune the size of that cache if they want).